# Sychronizing MDF file on a Local Machine to a webserver for project in C#

Tags: c#, sql, mdf, synchronize

I am developing a desktop application in c# and SQL Server. This application is installed on various clients machines on remote locations.The application installed on the machine has its own mdf file locally to store all the account and billing data of a client.Now we need to sync these mdf files from these client locations on a webserver.We are storing these mdf files separately on webserver because we need to access the data of every client separately to generate all the reports and returns of each client.

Please help me with some best solution of synchronizing mdf file from Local machine to webserver and vice versa.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your desktop application requirements, is it possible instead of having local copies of database files to have the desktop application connect to a central SQL Server instance?

That way the data is always in one place and makes your reporting requirements work.

Depending on what needs to be synchronized and how will affect your best solution:

- are there security/privacy constraints around the data you are copying around?
- are these just new records? If so, maybe a queue/push process on the desktop may help 
  update the reporting database
- are updates required? How will you merge these changes? (who is boss)?
- does the desktop application need the ENTIRE database contents? size may be a consideration

Comment: Thanks for answering Russell, we want to have a separate mdf for each client so that we can add the mdf file with installer/deployment for new clients and existing clients.and it doesnt need to connect the online db all the time.And we can create P/L Ac and Balance sheet separately on the cloud as an admin.Yes security constraints are there, that is why we are separating each clients db.No these are not always the new records (New or Edited). We need only the changes in the local file to be considered and update the online copy of the db..